# IOS- Views Are defined in Landscape application but running in portrait mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, orientation

my iOS application is running in Landscape! my viewController xib file are set to Landscape orientation I have also forced Landscape mode through all the code I can rest my hand on! still my views are running in portrait! 
same result on simulators and devices! same result on different Xcode versions

I have already followed this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2244/_index.html

Screen shot:
[image]

Comment: Have u try from targets.... ?And can u tell xcode version.?

Comment: xcode version 4, 5 and 6 and target 7.1 and earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method of **appdelegate.m** file, add below line:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

Answer (score 0):

solved - I missed this line in appdelegate didfinishLaunch()

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```